# Does the Mac "Do Not Disturb" function affect Skype calls?

Tags: notifications, skype

If I use Notification Center's "Do Not Disturb" toggle, will I still receive Skype phone/video calls?

I know this toggle will temporarily disable banners/alerts, as those notifications are actually routed through Notification Center, but calls have a popup dialog of their own.

If not, how can I temporarily disable Skype calls? Do I need to log out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skype has a "Do Not Disturb" function.  If you click on the lower right hand corner of your avatar, you can select your status.

[image]

When you select "Do Not Disturb" you will not receive any notifications from Skype.

Comment: Interesting. So then do Skype calls go to voicemail, if set up?

Comment: Yes.  It will go to voicemail.

Comment: This answer does not address the main question about the macOS “do not disturb” toggle affecting Skype.

Comment: @YoYo the question says "**If not** how can I ...."  It *inherently* answers the question.

Comment: so answer with “macOS feature cannot suppress ... instead ...”?